# Equivalence of Group Actions, Transitivity, and Conjugate Subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, equivalence-relations, group-actions

**Some Preliminary Definitions and Properties:**

Actions of a group $G$ on sets $X$ and $Y$ are **equivalent** if the corresponding action of $G$ on maps from $X$ to $Y$ fixes some bijection. In this case, we write $X \sim Y$.

An action is said to be **transitive** if it has only one orbit.

Given an action of a group $G$ on a set $X$,

the **stabilizer**, $G_x$, of $x$ is defined by

$$ G_x = \{ g \in G : gx = x \}; $$

and the **orbit**, $Gx$, of $x$ is defined by

$$ Gx = \{ gx : g \in G \}. $$

Properties:

(i) $Gx \subset X$ and $G_x \le G$;

(ii) there exists a bijection from $Gx$ to the coset space $G/G_x$; and

(iii) if $G$ is finite, then $|Gx|=|G/G_x|$.

**The Statement of the Problem:**

Prove the following:

(a) For each subgroup $H$ of a group $G$, the action $G$ by left translation on the left coset space $G/H$ is transitive.

(b) Each transitive action of a group $G$ on a set $X$ is equivalent to the action $G$ by left translation on the coset space $G/G_x$, for each $x \in X$.

(c) For subgroups $H$ and $K$ of $G$, the left translation actions of $G$ on $G/H$ and $G/K$ are equivalent if and only if $H$ and $K$ are conjugate.

**Where I Am:**

For part (a): The action of $G$ by left translation on the left coset space $G/H$ has only one orbit and is, thus, transitive. (i.e., since $gH=g \cdot H$, the orbit of $H \in G/H$ is the whole coset space.) [I pretty much understand this. It was mostly the result of piecing together definitions and properties, but doesn't make too much intuitive sense to me.]

For part (b): Since $Gx \subset X$ and we are considering transitive actions of $G$ on $X$ (i.e., actions with only one orbit), in this case, $Gx = X$ [I'm not actually sure if this is true, but it seems correct. I would like to be able to prove it, but can't seem to figure out how]. We know that there exists a bijection $f: Gx \to G/G_x$, so it must also be the case that $f$ maps from $X$ to $G/G_x$ bijectively. [Here, I need to prove that the action of $G$ on $f$ fixes $f$, which I can't figure out how to do.] Since the action of $G$ on $f$ fixes $f$, we have that $X \sim G/G_x$, as desired.

For part (c): I have made the least amount of progress on this one. To show that $H$ and $K$ are conjugate, I assume that I need to show that $K = gHg^{-1}$, for some $g \in G$, and $H = gKg^{-1}$, for some $g \in G$. I can see how this'd be the case if these subgroups were *normal* in $G$, but I can't seem to get it from the assumptions given. Obviously, this statement is biconditional, so I have to prove the other direction, as well; but I'd be happy to get at least One Direction$^{\text{TM}}$.

Answer (score 4):

Since I refered to this thread while answering another, I might as well answer this one, albeit being more than two years late.  First, yes, if $X$ is a left $G$-set, then $G$ acts on $X$ transitively if and only if $G\cdot x=X$ for at least one (whence for any) $x\in X$.

For Part (a), you got it correctly.  For Part (b), for a fixed $x\in X$, we define a function $f:X\to G/G_x$ as $f(y)=gG_x$, if $y\in X$ and $g\in G$ satisfy $y=g\cdot x$ (since $G$ acts on $X$ transitively, such an element $g\in G$ exists for every $y\in X$).  Here, $G_x$ is the stabilizer of $x$, namely $G_x:=\big\{g\in G\,\big|\,g\cdot x=x\big\}$.  We need to prove that $f$ is well defined.  Suppose that $y=g\cdot x$ and $y=h\cdot x$ for $g,h\in G$.  We have to prove that $gG_x=hG_x$.  This is easy, since

$$\begin{align}
(h^{-1}g)\cdot x&=h^{-1}\cdot(g\cdot x)\\
&=h^{-1}\cdot y\\
&=h^{-1}\cdot(h\cdot x)\\
&=(h^{-1}h)\cdot x\\
&=1_G\cdot x=x,
\end{align}$$

whence $h^{-1}g\in G_x$, and so $gG_x=hG_x$.  Injectivity of $f$ is clear: if $f(y)=f(z)$ for some $y=g\cdot x$ and $z=h\cdot x$ with $g,h\in G$, then $g G_x=h G_x$, or $h^{-1}g\in G_x$, whence

$$\begin{align}
y&=g\cdot x\\
&=(hh^{-1}g)\cdot x\\
&=h\cdot\big((h^{-1}g)\cdot x\big)\\
&=h\cdot x\\
&=z.
\end{align}$$

Surjectivity of $f$ is also immediate: for $g\in G$, we have $f(g\cdot x)=g G_x$.

For Part (c), we assume first that there exists an isomorphism of left $G$-sets $\phi:G/H\to G/K$.  Suppose that $\phi(H)=kK$ for some $k\in G$.  We know that $h\in H$ implies that $hH=H$, so

$$\begin{align}
kK&=\phi(H)\\
&=\phi(hH)\\
&=\phi(h\cdot H)\\
&=h\cdot\phi(H)\\
&=hkK.
\end{align}$$

This proves that $k^{-1}hk\in K$ for every $h\in H$.  That is, $k^{-1}Hk\subseteq K$.  On the other hand,

$$\begin{align}
\phi(k^{-1}H)&=\phi(k^{-1}\cdot H)\\
&=k^{-1}\cdot\phi(H)\\
&=k^{-1}\cdot (kK)\\
&=K.
\end{align}$$

If $t\in K$, then $tK=K$, so

$$\begin{align}
\phi(k^{-1}H)&=K\\
&=tK\\
&=t\cdot K\\
&=t\cdot \phi(k^{-1}H)\\
&=\phi\big(t\cdot (k^{-1}H\big)\\
&=\phi(tk^{-1}H).
\end{align}$$

Since $\phi$ is injective, $k^{-1}H=tk^{-1}H$, or $H=ktk^{-1}H$, which means $kKk^{-1}\subseteq H$, or equivalently $K\subseteq k^{-1}Hk$.  That is, $K=k^{-1}Hk$ is a conjugate of $H$.  Conversely, if $K=k^{-1}Hk$ for some $k\in G$, then we can define an isomorphism of left $G$-sets $\phi:G/H\to G/K$ by sending $gH\mapsto gkK$ for all $g\in G$.  It is not difficult to show that $\phi$ is well defined, injective, surjective, and compatible with the left $G$-actions on $G/H$ and on $G/K$.

In addition, if $X$ and $Y$ are transitive left $G$-sets, then $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic as left $G$-sets if and only if, for some $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$, the stabilizing subgroups $G_x$ and $G_y$ are conjugate subgroups of $G$.  This follows immediately from Part (b) and Part (c) of this problem.

**P.S.**  To avoid possible stupid problems with the empty set, all sets that appear in this answer are inherently assumed to be nonempty.